# How to display alert (validate messages) while using Html.BeginForm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, html.beginform

I'm using html.Beginform to navigate to action. I'm passing one parameter to it. The value for the parameter is retrieved from drop down. I want to check whether the drop down has been selected. If there is a click event I can easily validate. But I don't know how to achieve this without having click event.

Below is my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index (string Name)
{
}
```

Is it possible to achieve it using Javascipt rather than C#?

Comment: Are you using a model for your dropdown? how are you handling the post?

Comment: Yes I am using model for dropdown

Comment: Please provide your model too.

Comment: It's useful to validate model not only on client side but on server side too.

Answer (score 2):

When using a model, make sure to add

```
[Required]
```

on the item you wish to be required.

```
public class TheDropDownModel
{
    [Required]
    public string DropdownId { get; set; }
}
```

Then on the view add to show the validation summary.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
{
...dropdown code
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

..submit button
}
```

Change the controller to

```
public ActionResult Index (TheDropDownModel model)
{
}
```

Comment: For using @Html.ValidationSummary(true) should the drop down be inside form?

Comment: You you need it to be wrapped in the using statement

Answer (score 1):

**Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    ...
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyViewModel @* there should be setted full namespace for your model *@

@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, @* there should be your selectList *@)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    ...
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index (MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Some server logic for model validation
    }
}
```